# jQuery Mobile load data through file in Offline iOS app

Tags: html, css, ios, jquery-mobile

I just started playing with jQueryMobile. I am making an offline app for iOS. How can I read the file and display the contents in unordered list `<ul> <li>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look into HTML5 LocalStorage and use jQM to read and parse out the results for your ul list.

Live Example: http://jsfiddle.net/YDEjZ/15/